# Hubble Damping Intuition

Tags: cosmology, field-theory

When we calculate the equations of motion of, say, a scalar field in an expanding FLRW universe, the metric introduces the following `Hubble friction' to the equations of motion
$$
3 H\dot\phi\,.
$$
This term causes the energy density of fields to dilute. For example, a non-relativistic scalar field will have energy density that dilutes like $1/a^3$ where $a$ is the FLRW scale factor. In other words, what happens is exactly what one would expect. So, one possible justification for this term is "that's just how it has to be." However, my hope is that there another physics argument for why that term must show up, rather than an a posteriori justification.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I don't understand your question. You already know this term comes from the d'Alembertian in the FLRW metric of the Klein-Gordon equation with potential, and that ultimately the only explanation for everything is "that's the way things are". What kind of explanation are you seeking?

Comment: the term is coming from FLRW metric, so you want justification for FLRW metric?